# How to avoid storing the original content in Solr, only the indexed version?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, solr

I have a lot of documents about 30 TB, These docs have other attributes associated with it

1. don't want to store the actual documents after indexing it with Solr since there it is stored somewhere else and I can access it if needed later
2. The other data attributes will also be indexed with solr and won't be deleted.

I'm currently developing with Ruby on rails and have mysql but would like to move to 
Mongodb. Is the scenario above possible?

Thanks

-Maged

Comment: As I understand from your requirement, you want to index the data attributes of your document not the content of the document. Am I right?

Comment: Both, so think about it as text plus its attributes like user who read it, what category this text under, etc. So I would like to 1. store the text into the db  (mongodb) plus other fields and after it gets indexed, I would like to delete the text content from mongodb and keep it into  the search index. (The text part will never be updated, only the attributes will be updated). Hope that helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to store original content in Solr. That's the difference between **stored** and **indexed**. If you set **stored** to false, you will only keep the processed, tokenized version of content as needed for search. Just make sure you keep your ID stored. This is set in your field definition in **schema.xml**.

This does mean Solr cannot return any of the non-stored fields back to the user, so you need to match them to the original records based on IDs (just as you seem to suggest).

This also break the partial document updates, so you will need to make sure you are reindexing the whole document when things changed.

Comment: Thanks Alexandre for your reply. I thought it was possible , What about the size of Solr index of the tokenized content compared to the actual content, do you have an idea how much percentages it actually saves?

Comment: That depends on how you are tokenizing content and how many common words/tokens you end up with. Because Solr/Lucene uses Posting list, it does not repeat the same word (per field, I think). Instead it stores the word once and then just offsets. So, there is no good answer, just experimentation.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand, that you don't want to play with you content of the document. Once you'll index it and keep it. The other data properties, you want to index frequently. It's better you create your **"content"** field **stored** and **indexed** both, if you are not concerned about space. Choose the tokenizer and filters for content smartly, so that it creates less tokens.

For partial update, follow http://solr.pl/en/2012/07/09/solr-4-0-partial-documents-update/

Comment: I think you got part of the picture, so here is the scenario 1. I add a new content field in Mongodb +other properties. 2. Index both with solr 3. Delete Content from Mongodb and keep the properties 4. For future update, content won't be updated but other fields may. The reason I'm deleting the content is because of space issue and it is already stored somewhere else (have no control over it but able to access). I'm hoping that the index will be much smaller store than the actual content for search. I really don't want to store the content either in Mongodb or Solr